# How to change HTML of Categoty Page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, layout, filter, html

how can i change the layout of Category page in Magento 2
Like to change some HTML in category page.

[image]

i want to show product in full width and want to show price filter just above of product listing just below the menu.
How to do that ?
Any help is appriciated.

Comment: you can do it using applying css, and moving the block

Comment: Thanks for your response. then please tell me how to add custom class or i will use any given class @JigsParmar

Comment: you only want for category page?

Comment: yes @JigsParmar

Comment: than catalog-category-view class in body tag

Comment: thanks for your response 
i have used page-layout-2columns-left is that class create any problem ?@JigsParmar

Comment: not use that, its for 2xolumn layout, please use catalog-category-view

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below css

```
.catalog-category-view .columns {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.page-layout-2columns-left.catalog-category-view .column.main {
    width: 100%;
}

.page-layout-2columns-left.catalog-category-view .sidebar-main {
    width: 100%;
}
```